# problems with debugging a super basic chvt bot

Tags: python, debugging, chatbot

The first part of program should do the following

- Step 1: Load in the data. In your code, you can assume the filename is
  “spotify.csv.” The following are some of the data in this file and their meaning.
- Step 2: Ask the user the artist they want to select.
- Step 3: Display all the songs by this artist and report the records. Each record in your list should be a list or tuple, containing the values for artist, song name,
  danceability, energy, and valence.
- Step 4: Summarize the work by this artist by calculating the mean, maximum and
  minimum value for danceability, energy, tempo, and valence in all the songs by
  this artist. Do not use built-in function to

Here is my code so far:

```
MusicDatabase = open("spotify.csv", "r")

MusicDatabase.readline()

def artistSearch(artistName):
  
  foundList = []
  
  for data in MusicDatabase:
    
    dataList = data.split(",")

    for item in dataList:
     
      print(item)
     
      if item == artistName:
        foundList.append(item)
        print("Match!")

  MusicDatabase.close()

  return foundList


print(artistSearch(input("The artist you would like to select: ")))
```

Comment: And what happens when you run this?

Comment: You're checking every field for a match.  You know which field is the artist's name.  Just check that one field.  And if you're going to need to do math with some of those fields, shouldn't you keep ALL of the fields for matching records?

Comment: @TimRoberts It crashes apparently it says that the spotify.cvs file is too large I don't know  what seems to be the problem

Comment: If you're getting errors, please tell us the exact error you're getting and exactly which line causes it.  Your code will not depend on the size of the CSV file.

Comment: @TimRoberts in 3 line it shows me

Comment: Edit your question.  Tell us which line fails, and show us the EXACT ERROR you get.